# Last input text inside a form is filled automatically with username stored on Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, asp.net-core

Problem goes like this . Let's say I logged into my web using this account info : 'admin@ent.com ' and password : 'whatever' , and checked the Chrome option to keep it stored . Then , I log into the web using ANY account and load a particular page , which includes a simple form , and the last input text that's contained into that form will automatically fill the value 'admin@ent.com' ( the account I stored ) . I'm using ASP NET Core 2.1 with Razor Pages , so this is not and html but a cshtml file .

Is this some kind of Chrome bug , or am I doing something wrong ?

BTW: The form is meant to POST the data , so the form inputs should start empty.

This is how my inputs look like :

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="phone" class="col-sm-12 control-label">Phone</label>
    <div class="col-sm-12 inner-addon left-addon tabular-border">
            <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" asp-for="user.PhoneNumber">
    </div>
</div>
```

As you may see , it's a very common input field , and my form tag looks like this :

```
<form id="create_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

These are sreenshots showing the error/bug/whateveritis :

[image: last input auto filled with my account info ( domain part covered )]

EDIT : This picture shows the autocomplete box . The text below 'Gestionar Contraseñas' means 'Manage passwords' , it's Spanish.

[image]

Comment: Do you have same `id="phone"` on your login form in same domain? or a form with same `id="create_form"` in login page?

Comment: Have you tried by adding `autocomplete="off"`  attribute to the input field?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour no I don't , and it's not a problem with that specific input , I've tried removing the input and the problem persist always with the last text input within the form.

Comment: @TanvirArjel Yes , it doesn't work.  It seems to be a different kind of 'autocomplete box' , maybe it's new on Chrome (I'd never seen it before) . I'm adding a new pic to the question to explain this better .